# How to apply dynamic shape with tensorflow `scatter_nd`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

In tensorflow, how can I apply dynamic shape to `scatter_nd`?

When I use an input tensor with a dynamic shape, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor:
>   (20, ?)

Here is the function I use. It works when `tensor` has a static shape. But with a dynamic shape (e.g. `(?, 7)`) it fails.

```
def tf_zero_pad_columns(tensor, columns_list, num_output_columns):
    assert(tensor.shape.as_list()[1] == len(columns_list))
    assert(num_output_columns >= len(columns_list))

    tensor = tf.transpose(tensor)
    columns = tf.constant(np.array([columns_list]).T.astype('int32'))
    shape=tf.TensorShape((num_output_columns, tensor.get_shape()[1]))
    scattered = tf.scatter_nd(columns, tensor, shape=shape)
    return tf.transpose(scattered)
```

I also tried replacing `tensor.get_shape()[1]` by `-1` but this produces a different error during training:

> InvalidArgumentError: Dimension -1 must be >= 0    [[Node:
>   lambda_40/ScatterNd ....

---

**EDIT:**

Example input with a dynamic shape (this reproduces the error):

```
tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 7))
tf_zero_pad_columns(tensor, [11,12,13,4,5,6,7], 20)
```

Example input with a static shape:

```
import numpy as np
tensor_np = np.tile(range(7), (4, 1)) + np.array(range(4))[:, None]
tensor = tf.constant(tensor_np)


tf_zero_pad_columns(tensor, [11,12,13,4,5,6,7], 20)
```

Output is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Can you provide an input and an expected output?

Comment: With a static shape should be fine. I want to see how the function is supposed to work so maybe I will think of a workaround that will function with dynamic shapes.

Comment: @gorjan: I added expected input and outputs with dynamic and static shapes. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if the solution I posted does the thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def tf_zero_pad_columns(tensor, columns_list, num_output_columns):
    assert(tensor.shape.as_list()[1] == len(columns_list))
    assert(num_output_columns >= len(columns_list))

    tensor = tf.transpose(tensor)
    columns = tf.constant(np.array([columns_list]).T.astype('int32'))
    tensor_shape = tf.shape(tensor)[1]
    scattered = tf.scatter_nd(columns, tensor, shape=(num_output_columns, tensor_shape))
    return tf.transpose(scattered)
```